# Omitting <?> unintuitively breaks this code

Tags: java, generics, foreach

I have created a MWE where changing a single line by adding `<?>` solves a compiler error.

The following code does not compile:

```
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {

    public void traverse() {
        List<MyEntity> list = null /* ... */;
        for (MyEntity myEntity : list) {
            for (String label : myEntity.getLabels()) { // <-- Offending Line
                /* ... */
            }
        }
    }

    interface MyEntity<T> {
        T get();

        List<String> getLabels();
    }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
Error:(9, 51) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

Changing the definition in the offending line from `MyEntity myEntity` to `MyEntity<?> myEntity` solves the issue. I wonder why is the return type of this for-each treated as an `Object` and not as a `String`, unless I add the wildcard to the parent class? Note that `getLabels()` itself does not contain generics.

According to [Chapter 14.14.2. of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), a for-each is compiled to a loop using an iterator. Interestingly, expanding the for-each to such an iterator manually **works**:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = myEntity.getLabels().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String label = iterator.next();
    /* ... */
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Nice one, never seen that before

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, method body of your code example can be simplified to:

```
public void traverse() {
    MyEntity myEntity = null;
    for (String label : myEntity.getLabels()) { // <--  Offending Line
            /* ... */
    }
}
```

Why is that happening? Because when you declare variable `myEntity` (it doesn't matter where - in for-loop or as in my example) as `MyEntity myEntity`, you declare it as ***raw*** type, which eliminates generic type from return type of method `getLabels` as well: so it becomes just like `List getLabels();`, where obviously `Object` type is expected for for-loop construction.

In the same time `Iterator<String> iterator = myEntity.getLabels().iterator();` works fine, because you are specifying type here explicitly: `Iterator<String>`.

---

Very similar example is given in [JLS 4.8 "Raw types"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) which explains why does it happen:

> ...Inherited type members that depend on type variables will be
>   inherited as raw types as a consequence of the rule that the
>   supertypes of a raw type are erased...
>
> Another implication of the rules above is that a generic inner class
>   of a raw type can itself only be used as a raw type:

```
class Outer<T>{
     class Inner<S> {
         S s;
     }
}
```

> It is not possible to access Inner as a partially raw type (a "rare"
>   type):

```
Outer.Inner<Double> x = null; // illegal
```

---

**UPD-2**: As I received questions about `Iterator<String> iterator = myEntity.getLabels().iterator();`, why does it ok to do so, while first example doesn't work?

I personally agree that it looks confusing. But such are the rules. This case is also covered in same JLS paragraph with this example:

```
class Cell<E> {
    E value;

    Cell(E v)     { value = v; }
    E get()       { return value; }
    void set(E v) { value = v; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell x = new Cell<String>("abc");
        System.out.println(x.value);  // OK, has type Object
        System.out.println(x.get());  // OK, has type Object
        x.set("def");                 // unchecked warning
    }
}
```

---

More careful explanation about why does `Iterator<String> iterator = myEntity.getLabels().iterator();` work from JLS are based on this rule:

> That is, the subtyping rules (§4.10.2) of the Java programming
>   language make it possible for a variable of a raw type to be assigned
>   a value of any of the type's parameterized instances

In same way you can always write well-compiled code as:

```
    List<String> labels = myEntity.getLabels();
    for (String label : labels) { // <-- OK, no error here
            /* ... */
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I need some further clarification though: Assuming that, as you stated, declaring `myEntity` as raw also makes all members raw, how can I then store the result of `myEntity.getLabels()` in a (non-raw!) `Iterator<String>`? Shouldn't this also be illegal, then?

Comment: This is little bit different situation. `Iterator<E> iterator()` contains type variable, not generic type. When you do specify this type in `Iterator<String> iterator` you are factually "restore" this type, that is why it works even is `list` it self is raw type. **But**, because it is not direct way of specifying type it will give you compile-time *unchecked warning*.

Comment: It's confusing that `List<String> labels = myEntity.getLabels()` is A-OK for the compiler then. Is it because of some type coercition allowed in the assignment ?

Comment: @FabienBenoit-Koch please look at my update, may be it can give you some clue

Comment: @Andremoniy The "restore" part of your comment clarified it for me. So thanks to your answer, I learned that declaring a raw type makes **all** of its members raw, even members that are not related at all the the type parameter of the class itself. Thanks!!

Comment: @MichaelBorkowski Well, I should be honest with you: term **restore** is not very good here, it is my invention and it doesn't appear in JLS. It is some *way of thinking*. Generally what you probably should hold in mind, that such way of mixing *raw* and *parameter typing* is not welcome, as it is written in JLS: *The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into
the Java programming language is strongly discouraged*.

Comment: @MichaelBorkowski *the subtyping rules (§4.10.2) of the Java programming language make it possible for a variable of a raw type to be assigned a value of any of the type's parameterized instances*

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes, I just adopted your usage of "restored" :) I'm aware of the fact that I can assign a `List` to any `List<T>`, my IDE actually gave warnings but I had them ignored for other reasons, which caused me to overlook why the manual iterator solution worked. Furthermore, I thought raw types and <?> were basically synonymous, which I just learned is not the case. Thanks for clarifying everything!